# RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded with vanilla JS

Tags: post, get, fetch

I'm finishing my first project where I POST data to a server and then retrieve it in the form of a list on a separate page.  I have gotten to the point where I can now post and retrieve the data, however I'm getting this error:

Uncaught RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded
at renderSearchResults (menu.js:8)
at renderSearchResults (menu.js:38)

My code is below.  Any help would be appreciated.

```
var userInfo = JSON.parse(sessionStorage.getItem('user'));

function search() {
/* var userInfo = JSON.parse(sessionStorage.getItem('user')); */
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.open('GET', (`https://ict4510.herokuapp.com/api/menus?api_key=${userInfo.user.api_key}` ));

xhr.onload = function renderSearchResults() {
    if (this.status == 200) {
        var menuInfo = JSON.parse(this.responseText);

        var output = '';

        for (var i in menuInfo.menu) {
            
            
            
            output +=
                '<div class="foodItems">' +
                '<ul>' +
                '<li>Food Item: ' + menuInfo.menu[i].item + '</li>' +
                '<li>Description: ' + menuInfo.menu[i].description + '</li>' +
                '<li> Price: ' + menuInfo.menu[i].price + '</li>' +

                '</ul>' +   

                +

                '</div>';

        }

        console.log(output);

        document.getElementById('foods').innerHTML = output;
    }

    renderSearchResults();
}

xhr.send();

}

search();
```

Comment: You are calling renderSearchResults() inside itself (xhr.onload = function renderSearchResults()). while leads to recursion and hence the error  "Maximum call stack size exceeded at renderSearchResults"

Comment: fixed by removing renderSearchResults() function from the code and replacing simply with function()